# Can´t connect to MongoDb in deployment (Heroku): connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, deployment

My app runs fine locally but the server (connecting to the database) doesn´t when deployed on Heroku.

By reading the log and surfing in SO I think is because of the following line:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/shareable-todo-new')
    .then((res) => console.log(res)).catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

**My package.json :**

```
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"start": "node ./app.js",
"dev": "nodemon ./app.js",
"heroku-postbuild":"NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix front && npm run build --prefix front"
},
```

Tried adding this in my package.json but hasn´t helped:

```
 "heroku config":"set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true"
```

**My app.js :**

```js
const express = require('express')
const https = require('https')
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const path = require('path')

const routerLists = require('./routes/lists');
const routerTasks = require('./routes/tasks')
const routerUsers = require('./routes/users')

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/shareable-todo-new', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
        .then((res) => console.log(res)).catch((err) => console.log(err));
// fix a deprecated bugs
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

// Serve static assets if In Production:
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use('/api', routerLists)
app.use('/api', routerTasks)
app.use('/api', routerUsers)

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
    // set static folder:
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "front/build")))
    app.get("*", (req,res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'front', 'build', 'index.html'))
    })
}
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
  });
// middleware para admitir errores:
app.use((err,res) => {
    res.status(422).send({
        error: err.message
    })
})
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4000, () => console.log('express listening now...'))
```

If it´s of any help, when I try to do POST requests the chrome console gives error 500

Comment: There is no mongodb on the server. "mongodb://localhost" tells the driver to connect to the database hosted on the same machine that runs the script.

Comment: Right, do you know what´s usually put there (instead of localhost) when people deploy it to online services?

Comment: People usually put srv addresses of the online database

Comment: "Tried adding this in my package.json but hasn't helped` "heroku config":"set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true"`"—why would you do that? If you want to set an environment variable use [config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

Comment: Have you added a MongoDB add-on?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to 127.0.0.1 (or localhost) means your local machine. When you running your application on Heroku, 127.0.0.1 is the Heroku machine which does not contain MongoDB instance. You should use external server for hosting MongoDB, for example, https://mlab.com/

After deploying MongoDB to server, set environment variable (MONGODB_URI) to appropriate value

Comment: OP is already trying to connect to `process.env.MONGODB_URI` if it is present, and it should be set on Heroku if the correct addon has been provisioned.

Comment: @Chris, but the error message is saying that he is trying to reach MongoDB on localhost

Comment: Only because that environment variable isn't set: `mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/shareable-todo-new', ...)`. Again, this indicates that the addon likely isn't configured properly.

Comment: @Chris, I said this in my answer.

Comment: Except, OP _shouldn't_ set that variable. The _addon_ will do it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

When you develop and test on your local PC (localhost or 127.0.0.1), you have your code, development environment, the server and the MongoDB instance setup locally on port 27017(or any other). But when you deploy the code to Heroku and try to run your app, Heroku will definitely throw some kind of error because it has not configured any MongoDB instance on the server (that is .herokuapp.com). It is good if you find a way to create an instance which is really hard.

The best recommended way is to connect your application to the MongoDB cloud. As said in the above answer by Oleksandr, you have to create an account on mlab or MongoDB Atlas.

Place the following code snippet in the javascript file in which the code for starting your server is present.

```js
//the following URL will be provided once you create an account on MongoDB Atlas and create 
//a cluster. 
mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://<database_user_name>:<password>@cluster.address/<db_name>?retryWrites=true&w=majority`,{
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    useUnifiedTopology:true //this line is not mandatory
}).then(()=>{
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB Cloud :)');
})//catch errors if you want.
```

Other CRUD operations should work normally and make sure you have a good internet connection if you develop and make CRUD operations on MongoDB cloud from your localhost:port.

That should help! :)

Comment: OP is already trying to connect to `process.env.MONGODB_URI` if it is present, and it should be set on Heroku if the correct addon has been provisioned.